# comparing objects in useState and if there is object with same id keep one of them

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

i'm react beginner, for some reason when i console log i get two japans any advices ?

these are my data:

options initial value (comes from props) is:

`[{ id: 1, name: 'Japan' },{ id: 4, name: 'Australia' }, { id: 5, name: 'Poland' }];`

and from redux i'm getting this:

`[{ id: 1, name: 'Japan' }, { id: 2, name: 'America' }, { id: 3, name: 'Sweden' }];`

but my expected out put is :

`[{ id: 1, name: 'Japan' },{ id: 4, name: 'Australia' }, { id: 5, name: 'Poland' }, { id: 2, name: 'America' }, { id: 3, name: 'Sweden' }]`

```js
   const getUnselectedValues = useSelector(UnselectedValues);

 
 const [options, setOptions] = useState(
    props.selectedValues
      ? (
          [...props.selectedValues, ...getUnselectedValues] 
        ).filter((e ) => e)
      : [...getUnselectedValues]
  );
  
  console.log('options:', options)
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
const [options, setOptions] = useState(
    props.selectedValues
      ? Object.values([...props.selectedValues, ...getUnselectedValues].reduce((acc, {id, name}) =>(acc[id] ??= {id, name}, acc),{}))
      : [...getUnselectedValues]
  );
```

**Approach**:

1. Iterate through the merged array and build a dictionary by using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) where the key is the `id` and the value is `{id, value}`
2. In every iteration look up in the dictionary whether has the key in it or not. If the key is not present that means it's a unique entry and inserts it. If the key is already in the dictionary that means the entry is not unique so no need to insert it again.

Here is an example in Vanilla JS so you can play around:

```js
const selectedValues = [{ id: 1, name: 'Japan' },{ id: 4, name: 'Australia' }, { id: 5, name: 'Poland' }];

const getUnselectedValues = [{ id: 1, name: 'Japan' }, { id: 2, name: 'America' }, { id: 3, name: 'Sweden' }];


const res = Object.values([...selectedValues, ...getUnselectedValues].reduce((acc, {id, name}) =>(acc[id] ??= {id, name}, acc),{}));

console.log(res);
```

**Using `filter()`:**

```js
const selectedValues = [{ id: 1, name: 'Japan' },{ id: 4, name: 'Australia' }, { id: 5, name: 'Poland' }];

const getUnselectedValues = [{ id: 1, name: 'Japan' }, { id: 2, name: 'America' }, { id: 3, name: 'Sweden' }];

const res = [...selectedValues, ...getUnselectedValues.filter(({id, name}) => !selectedValues.find(it => it.id === id))];

console.log(res);
```

Comment: @walee I actually upvoted it! Yes it's possible to do with `filter()` as well so in this case you need to do loop nesting which is quite inefficient.

Comment: i will accept your answer, but could you provide filtering part here in comments ? i want to learn both ways

Comment: @walee well let me do it and I'll update the answer.

Comment: @walee have updated the answer as per your requirement.

Comment: any idea with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74648374/getting-objects-from-from-array-of-objects