# getting objects from from array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, jsx

I have an array of objects and some of those objects has groups which is an array,

i want all those objects from all groups and put it into one array of object, any idea how this could be done ?

what i want to have is this : `GroupData= [ { id: "679d8044", name: "group 3" }, { id: "b9342eb8", name: "group 1" } ];`

any idea ? english is not my mother language so could be mistakes.

you can try it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-list-array-of-objects-forked-rk34fj?file=/src/index.js

my code:

```js
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const mydata = [
  {
    name: "living room",
    groups: ""
  },
  {
    groups: [
      {
        id: "679d8044",
        name: "group 3"
      }
    ],
    name: "Area 1"
  },
  {
    groups: [
      {
        id: "b9342eb8",
        name: "group 1"
      }
    ],
    name: "Area 2"
  }
];

const GroupData = mydata.find((grup) => grup.groups);

console.log(GroupData);

const App = () => <div></div>;

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap).

```js
const mydata = [
  {
    name: "living room",
    groups: ""
  },
  {
    groups: [
      {
        id: "679d8044",
        name: "group 3"
      }
    ],
    name: "Area 1"
  },
  {
    groups: [
      {
        id: "b9342eb8",
        name: "group 1"
      }
    ],
    name: "Area 2"
  }
];

const GroupData = mydata.flatMap((grup) => grup.groups);

console.log(GroupData)
```

I did notice you are using an empty string for your groups when there are no values. It's best to keep consistency within your data. In your example, I would recommend changing from `groups: ""` to `groups: []` to indicate an empty group.

```js
const mydata = [
  {
    name: "living room",
    groups: []
  },
  {
    groups: [
      {
        id: "679d8044",
        name: "group 3"
      }
    ],
    name: "Area 1"
  },
  {
    groups: [
      {
        id: "b9342eb8",
        name: "group 1"
      }
    ],
    name: "Area 2"
  }
];

const GroupData = mydata.flatMap((grup) => grup.groups);

console.log(GroupData)
```

Comment: what if groups is empty or undefined null ... ?

Comment: and is it possible to check if its empty string doesnt print it just if its an array ?

Comment: You can always filter out the results once you've mapped them @walee. If you want a quick and easy "filter all falsy" values out you could use `mydata.flatMap((grup) => grup.groups).filter(Boolean)`. More advanced logic could be used within the filter if that doesn't suit your needs.

Comment: i used filter((e: any) => e)  after it and it fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
const mydata = [
  {
    name: "living room",
    groups: ""
  },
  {
    groups: [
      {
        id: "679d8044",
        name: "group 3"
      }
    ],
    name: "Area 1"
  },
  {
    groups: [
      {
        id: "b9342eb8",
        name: "group 1"
      }
    ],
    name: "Area 2"
  }
];

let groupData = [];

mydata.map((d) => {
  if (Array.isArray(d.groups)) {
    d.groups.map((group) => {
      groupData.push(group)
    })
    console.log(groupData)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.flatmap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and need to check `group` is an array or not. If the `group` is not an array we don't need to include it in the final array, so instead we return `[]` so `flatmap` makes it an empty element.

```js
const mydata = [{ name: "living room", groups: "" }, { groups: [ { id: "679d8044", name: "group 3" } ], name: "Area 1" }, { groups: [ { id: "b9342eb8", name: "group 1" } ], name: "Area 2" }];

const isArr = (arr) => Array.isArray(arr);
const res = mydata.flatMap(({groups}) => (isArr(groups) && groups) || []);
console.log(res);
```